# Proof: Let $C \subseteq [0,1]$ be uncountable, show that $C \cap [a,1]$ is uncountable for some $a \in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I have a question regarding the following exercise from Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis - 2nd edition:

Let $C \subseteq [0,1]$ be uncountable. Show that exists $a \in (0,1)$ such that $C \cap [a,1] $ is uncountable

Actually, someone already asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452550/let-c-subseteq-0-1-be-uncountable-show-there-exists-a-in-0-1-such-tha). However I came up with a slightly different proof and I would appreciate some comments on the correctness.

First we define $ S:= \{ a \in (0,1] \, | \, s.t. \ C \ \cap [a,1] \  \text{is countable}   \}$. Clearly $S$ is bounded from below by 0 and non-empty as $1$ is always an element of S. Thus it follows from the Axiom of Completness that $ s := \inf(S)$ exists. It also holds that $ s > 0 $, as $s = 0$ would implicate that $C \cap (0,1]$ is countable, however then $ C = \{0 \} \ \cup \ (C \ \cap \ (0,1] ) $  would be countable as an union of two countable sets, which contradicts our initial assumption.
It follows that for $a:= s/2 $ it holds that $1 > a > 0$  and also $C \ \cap [a,1]$ is uncountable as $s > a$ and thus $a \notin S $.

Thanks for your feedback,
Max

Comment: Your proof looks good to me. Nice approach!

Comment: "It also holds that s>0, as s=0 would implicate that C∩(0,1] is countable" you might want to explain this a bit more

Comment: @ZacharySelk Isnt this observation as hard as the original problem?

Comment: The trouble is that we don't know whether $\inf(S)\in S$.

Comment: @clark My point